# How do I implement a Gaussian activation function in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gaussian

I read that adding a new function is [not so straightforward](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#adding-a-new-op) in [this answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-custom-activation-functions-in-TensorFlow-for-Neural-Networks), so that is not a viable option. Also it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208111/in-tensorflow-do-i-need-to-add-new-op-for-sinc-or-gaussian-activation-funct) that it is possible to implement Gaussian using the tools made available by tensorflow. Can someone please give a detailed answer on how to exactly implement a Gaussian activation function in tf such that it behaves like a normal non-linear function and can be trained by back-prop ?

Comment: That's not necessarily how SO works. Show what you have done in order to implement this function and at what point you got stuck instead of asking for a complete solution...

Comment: Isnt it straightforward to implement it using tf.exp()?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code service

Comment: I am not voting for a close as the underlying problem is interesting, but it would be great to edit the question to be more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to implement a complex function in tensorflow, you can use all the basic mathematic functions that tensorflow provides and many of the common functions will be implemented.

Those functions provided by tensorflow's api are usually implemented with gradient descent compatibility in mind. So if you implement your complex function using derivable tensorflow operations, your function will be compatible with gradient descent.

So when you have a new function to implement, search for its mathematical formula, most of the time you will find corresponding mathematical operations in tensorflow.

(To provide a specific, ready to use answer for your particular problem is not in the best interest of you or SO), but check the formula of a gaussian function and it should be easy to implement.

Comment: "So if you implement your complex function using derivable tensorflow operations, your function will be compatible with gradient decent." This solves it.